Unity - Assign properties on game object creation best practice
New to unity and I am unsure of what makes sense here for best practice. I have a spawner that periodically creates new powerups the type of power up (bomb, blaster..ect) created is random. Here are the two ways that seem to work for creating this behavior:
Spawner.cs
public void spawnPowerUp()
{

    // Add a powerup to the game hierarchy
    GameObject powerUpObject = Instantiate(powerUp, randomSpotOnPlayfield(), transform.rotation);

    // Assign a random powerup to this instance
    powerUpObject.GetComponent<PowerUp>().powerUpType = (PowerUpTypes)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Enum.GetValues(typeof(PowerUpTypes)).Length);
}


The issue with this is that my spawner shouldn't really care what type of power up it created. I want separation of concerns. The logic of selecting a random powerup feels like it should be handled within the powerUp class. The only way I can think to do that is writing code like this:
PowerUp.cs
public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PowerUpTypes powerUpType;

    void Start()
    {
        RandomizePowerUpType();
    }

    public void RandomizePowerUpType()
    {
        powerUpType = (PowerUpTypes)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Enum.GetValues(typeof(PowerUpTypes)).Length);
    }
}


PowerUpTypes.cs
public enum PowerUpTypes
{
    Bomb, Blaster
}


Questions asking for "best practices" are likely to be closed; but it depends on your requirements for your powerup class. If you want every powerup to always be a random type, then you can put it in the Start method. If you ever want a powerup to be a specific type, then it'd have to be set by an outside function anyways. Alternatively, you could have a PowerupSpawner class inherit from Spawner; and only worry about setting a type in the new class to make Spawner more generic.
